# How to switch to non-graphical view in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, linux-terminal, virtual-terminal

I've recently installed Ubuntu. It's graphical; how can I switch to command-line mode so that everything is to be typed, like DOS?

Comment: CTRL + ALT + F3 for Ubuntu 17.10 onward.

Answer (score 16):

On recent versions of Ubuntu, there are several (by default 7) "virtual terminals", each of which can have its own display environment. By default, VTs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 contain text-mode Linux consoles, and VT 7 contains an X session (graphical Linux desktop).

The default command to switch to VT *n* is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F*n*</kbd>. So to switch to a non-graphical view, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>. Note that you have to log in separately on each virtual terminal. After switching, enter your username and password to get to a Bash prompt.

To switch back to your graphical session, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>. (If you have logged in using "switch user", to get back to your graphical X session you may have to use Ctrl-Alt-F8 instead, since "switch user" creates an additional VT to allow multiple users to run graphical sessions simultaneously.) If you're done with the text-mode session, first press Ctrl-D at the Bash prompt to log out of that session (otherwise, other people could get to a logged-in session, bypassing your password check).

Note that you *don't* have to do this to type commands at the command-line: [You can use a terminal program like `gnome-terminal` within your graphical session (see Pavium's answer).](https://superuser.com/a/100694/34598)

Comment: how to login in virtual terminal, it alway prompt "login incorrect"

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 18.04 allows me to go to terminal mode with Ctrl+Alt+F3 and back to GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

I realize this is an old post, but it still can be useful today.

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessary to completely shut down the GUI.

The interface for the command-line is called 'Terminal', in Applications/Accessories.

If you *do* want to shutdown the GUI (the X server), see [Ubuntu Linux - shutdown the X server](https://theos.in/news/ubuntu-linux-shutdown-the-x-server/)

Comment: Is it convenient to switch back and force ?

Comment: @PHP: The terminal **pavium** is referring to is a window within the GUI so switching back and forth between windows is as easy as Alt-tab or a mouse click.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu (like other Unix-variants) has multiple Terminals. The graphical console you are seeing is on 7. The first 6 are text consoles. You can switch between text consoles by using ALT+[number of terminal]. To switch from the graphical console you will have to add STRG to that command.

Comment: STRG=Ctrl on some keyboards